# Applying reduction formula to integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, reduction-formula

**Question**

For $n \geq 0$, let $$I_n = \int_{0}^{8} x^n(8 - x)^\frac 1 3\ \mathrm{d}x\ .$$

Show that, for $n \geq 1$, $$I_n = \frac {24n} {3n + 4} I_{n - 1}\ .$$

---

**My working**

Let $u = x^n$ and $v' = (8 - x)^{\frac 1 3}$

$\implies u' = nx^{n - 1}$ and $v = -\frac 3 4 (8 - x)^{\frac 4 3}$

$\implies I_n = [-\frac 3 4 x^n(8 - x)^{\frac 4 3}]^{x = 8}_{x = 0} + \frac 3 4 n \int_{0}^{8} x^{n - 1}(8 - x)^\frac 4 3\ \mathrm{d}x$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \frac 3 4 n \int_{0}^{8} x^{n - 1}(8 - x)^\frac 1 3(8 - x)\ \mathrm{d}x$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = \frac 3 4 n \int_{0}^{8} [8x^{n - 1}(8 - x)^\frac 1 3 - x^n(8 - x)^{\frac 1 3}]\ \mathrm{d}x$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ = 6nI_{n - 1} - \frac 3 4 n I_n$

$\implies (1 + \frac 3 4)I_n = 6nI_{n - 1}$

$\therefore I_n = \frac {24n} {3n + 4} I_{n - 1}$

---

I try to use integration by parts, but with my choices of $u$ and $v'$, I do not seem to be getting anywhere. I am currently taking an introductory module to calculus in college. In class, we have only gone through the reduction formula for $\sin$ and $\cos$ and I have been stuck at this question for quite some time. Any hints/intuitions as to how to proceed will be greatly appreciated :)

---

**Edit**

Following some help from Phicar, I have finally got it! :) (I have edited my post to include my updated working)

Comment: Show us what happens when you do integration by parts. Perhaps we can give you a hint there.

Comment: @Phicar Hello :) I have edited my post to include my working! It is very short because I got stuck really fast.

Comment: Nice. What if, instead you take $u=x^{n}$ and $v'=(8-x)^{1/3}$? Seems more natural because with your approach you will have to integrate the $I_n$ which seems innecesary.

Comment: @Phicar Actually, I tried that at the very start, but I also got stuck, because I did not know how to deal with the $\frac 4 3$ in the exponent.

Comment: I posted then the hint that I think you are missing. Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $v'=(8-x)^{1/3},$ integrating you get, as implicit in your comment,$$v=-\frac{3}{4}(8-x)^{1/3+1}=-\frac{3}{4}(8-x)^{1/3}(8-x)=\frac{-24}{4}(8-x)^{1/3}+\frac{3x}{4}(8-x)^{1/3}.$$
Split the integral in the addition sign.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it :) I have also edited my post to include my working and credits to you!

Comment: @EthanMark You are welcome. Good job!

Answer (score 1):

$$I_n=\int_0^8x^n(8-x)^{1/3}dx$$
$x=8u, dx=8du$
$$I_n=2\int_0^1\left(\frac u8\right)^n(1-u)^{1/3}du=2^{1-3n}\int_0^1u^n(1-u)^{1/3}du=2^{1-3n}B\left(n+1,\frac43\right)$$
you can use this as a quick sanity check for any values :)